# Validity of php variables

Tags: php, variables

It may sound silly but I'm quite php outdated/unexperienced and coming from Java programming back to php, so I mix up the concepts.

If in a php webpage I declare a variable

```
$debug=TRUE;
```

and try to access it from below within a function

```
a(){
    if ($debug){
    echo "I'm here";
    }
}
```

the variable doesn't exists or isn't initiated? The whole file is just simply:

```
<?php
$debug=TRUE;
a(){
    if ($debug){
        echo "I'm here";
    }
}
?>
```

Do I need to make a session variable or something else? I'm quite clueless & the same concept is confusing me for the use of other variables within. Also for the further use of variables, I am trying to be forced to pass all the variables I need forward to the function where I use them and a class concept as in Java perhaps would be cleaner but is a kind of too much for this simplicity. Or do I need the functions (it's a form processor) to be declared as a class?

I know this is silly, but I looked through Google and forums and the problem seems to be so obvious and simple that it's hard to find a webpage or entry targeting this (or perhaps I'm asking the wrong question).

Comment: If debug is in the global scope, you'll have to declare `global $debug;` at the beginning of your function scope.

Comment: you also need to put function in front of `a`

Comment: don't use global when you can just parse the variable to the function.

Comment: `$GLOBALS['debug']` should work as well if it's in the global scope. Scoping: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: How about reading the manual?

Comment: @Justin Swanhart: was it to me? If so - could you be so kind and explain it a bit.

Comment: No, it was for the poster.  I downvoted the question for lack of research.

Comment: need to make an answer instead of comment...

Comment: This site isn't a forum.  This is a question answer site.  Not every question on StackOverflow can be answered by reading a single manual page, but this one certainly can.

Comment: even after reading the manual.
It is silly to declare a variable global after its first initialisation...
additionally I've tested it and it doesn't help if I use chained method calls

$debug=TRUE;
function a(){
if ($debug){
//do something
}
b();
}

function b(){
if ($debug){
// do something
}

}

b() doesn't know the value of $debug?!?!?!?!

Comment: You need to declare a variable as being from the global scope in each function you want to use it in.  READ THE MANUAL!!!

Comment: I did! and still could not understand that stramnge definition of global.
in fact this is so contraintuitive coming from Java programming... therefore my question... because if you have to redeclare global in every function it's still not global but local scope. (or you tell php to handle in a local scope a variable as global) but the variable itself remains local...
the same is for the $_GLOBALS[] array which makes the code-writing also more complicated...
Bizarre, coming from java...
So back to spaghetticode...
Thanks anyway for your patience...

Comment: If you change the variable, it changes in global scope.  You aren't making a copy of the variable from global scope, the global variable maintains its global scope.  You just have to declare that you want to use a variable from global scope.  This allows you to have variables at local scope that have the same names as those in global scope without relying on namespaces.

Comment: @user1610628: don't you confuse java and javascript? Because Java has very similar scope resolution model to php's one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
<?php
$debug = TRUE;

function a() {
    global $debug;
    if($debug === TRUE) {
         echo "I'm here....\n"
    }
}
```

Better, instead of using globals you can pass it in as a parameter:

```
<?php
$debug = TRUE;

function a($debug = TRUE) {
  if($debug === TRUE) ....
}
```

You can also use the $_GLOBALS array:

```
<?php
$debug = TRUE;

function a() {
   if($_GLOBALS['debug'] === TRUE) ...
}
```

You can use constants, which are always in scope:

```
<?php
define('DEBUG', TRUE);

function a() {
  if(DEBUG === TRUE) ...
}
```

You can also use a singleton:

```
function a() {
    if(SingletonClass::get_instance()->debug === TRUE) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You'll have to create a singleton class which extends StdClass() to get implicit ->get and ->set methods.

http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1304-how-use-singleton-design-pattern.html

Comment: Even though globals is a root of all evil - perfectly valid answer, +1

Comment: Concerning: RTFM --> this is what I said: I didn't look for Variable scope but variable validity
google didn't show anything of value.

And concerning the practical help:
missing function was a typo nothing more...
Constants don't make sense, not all parameters are really constants (though most of them)

And generally what? globals are declared global after their initialisation? That is weird...
But thanks for the hint...

Comment: even after reading the manual.
It is silly to declare a variable global after its first initialisation...
additionally I've tested it and it doesn't help if I use chained method calls

$debug=TRUE;
function a(){
if ($debug){
//do something
}
b();
}

function b(){
if ($debug){
// do something
}

}

b() doesn't know the value of $debug?!?!?!?!

Comment: If you don't want to use the global keyword, then you have to use the $_GLOBALS "superglobal".  You don't have to use the global keyword in every function if you use the $_GLOBALS[] array.  The global keyword can be more convenient.  I gave you FOUR different ways to get a variable from global scope.  There aren't any other ways to do it in PHP.

Comment: Actually, FIVE ways...  I added a singleton option.

Comment: ok... thanks...
I guess I have to reprogram everything the php file again. I wanted to separate the codeparts to have handy small functions, but this is a killer issue and makes the code more complicated than I pretended originally.
so no functions are better and just one long codepiece
Crappy php concerning the variable scope...
But thanks that made myself clear why so much pages are coded in very long codepieces...

Answer (score 2):

did you want something like this:

```
<?php
$debug=TRUE;
function a($debug){
  if ($debug){
    echo "I'm here";
  }
}

a($debug);//outputs "I'm here"
?>
```

Comment: It's unlikely you ever debug in this way

Comment: It is very common to declare a debug variable at global scope, then print out status information to a log when it is set.  This is common for complex CLI scripts.  Using a define() is common too instead of a global.

Comment: Thanks dagon but passing the variable in this content doesn't make sense as there are many chained method calls...
global seems to be the only way...

Answer (score 2):

A few things here a(){} isn't defined as a function

```
function a(){

}
```

Next, you shouldn't try use globals unless you absolutely want them. But, you could

```
$debug = TRUE;
function a(){
global $debug;
if($debug)
{
echo "it is";
}
}
```

then call a() whenever you want to check it.

I must say I don't think this is a great practice in how you are trying to debug.

Comment: actually it's quite often practice and not that bad as you wanted to show

Comment: Something that is "practiced quite often" is not always a good practice :)

Comment: at least in Java it's standard debug process...
when entering: you print the MethodName and Variables, and when exiting: the methodName plus return param 
This is good practice if you jump over hundreds of (conditionally connected) methods without knowing the contents...

Comment: @Jared Drake: I didn't try to justify its quality by frequency. This is a normal practice

Answer (score 1):

Pass variables to a function, like this:

```
$debug = true;
function a($debug) {
    var_dump($debug);
}
a($debug);
// Outputs bool(true)
```

Comment: thanks but this is no option...
I have several chained method calls... this would overhead the method input params...